# PostgreSQL unnest() with consecutive integers grouped by number

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a distinct ordered array of integers, I am wanting to unnest the array and assign a group number to each batch of consecutive integers.

eg: {2,3,5,7,8,9,10,20,21,25} should return

```
elem | group_nr
-----+---------
   2 |  1
   3 |  1
   5 |  2
   7 |  3
   8 |  3
   9 |  3
  10 |  3
  20 |  4
  21 |  4
  25 |  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `lag()` and `sum()`:

```
with the_data(arr) as (
values (array[2,3,5,7,8,9,10,20,21,25])
)

select elem, sum(diff) over w as group_nr
from (
    select elem, (elem- 1 is distinct from lag(elem) over w)::int as diff
    from the_data, unnest(arr) as elem
    window w as (order by elem)
    ) s
window w as (order by elem);

 elem | group_nr 
------+----------
    2 |        1
    3 |        1
    5 |        2
    7 |        3
    8 |        3
    9 |        3
   10 |        3
   20 |        4
   21 |        4
   25 |        5
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at lag() and sum(), but couldn't get my head around how to bring it all together. I need to understand using window functions better. This will be used as part of a larger function with the array as an input, so I have simplified a bit (in my mind, anyway) to:

Comment: WITH tmp_diff AS (
 SELECT
     elem,
        (elem - 1 IS DISTINCT FROM lag(elem) OVER (ORDER BY elem))::INTEGER AS diff
    FROM unnest(ARRAY[2,3,5,7,8,9,10,20,21,25]) AS elem
)
SELECT
 elem,
    sum(diff) OVER (ORDER BY elem) AS group_nr
FROM tmp_diff;

Comment: It's ok of course, however I'd prefer a derived table (a subquery in FROM clause) over a WITH statement. In many cases the planner generates a better plan for the first variant. See [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/4933)

Comment: Thank you for the input. For my current use that perfomance difference doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag` after unnesting to get the difference of current and previous row's values and then use running sum to assign group numbers.

```
select id,num,sum(col) over(partition by id order by num) as grp
from (select id,num,case when num-lag(num,1,0) over(partition by id order by num)=1 then 0 else 1 end as col
      from (select id,unnest(array_column) as num from tbl) t
     ) t
```

Comment: The logic look similar to the above answer I accepted, but I can't see where "tbl" coems from.

Comment: `tbl` is the table name containing the data. I assumed you needed to do this for several rows in the table. Hence an `id` column.